# ModernCV phone symbol

Tags: symbols, moderncv

I'm trying to build a CV on LaTeX using the `moderncv` template. I have a phone symbol added at the top of the CV for my own telephone number as this was part of the program template, however I would like to use the same symbol for the telephone numbers of my references. LaTeX simply won't process my further `\phone` command. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Would you be able to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current state? It should show the way you include your references, as well as how you use your credentials at the top of your CV. It'll make it easier to provide solutions that suit your needs.

Answer (score 5):

The phone symbols are defined by `moderncv` itself as `\mobilephonesymbol`, `\fixedphonesymbol` and `\faxphonesymbol` (as of version 1.4.0).

Answer (score 4):

The package `bbding` provides independently commands `\PhoneHandset` and `\Phone`, so you can even take an other symbol. See:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbding}

\begin{document}
\huge

\Phone

\PhoneHandset

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
\mobilesymbol
\phonesymbol
\faxsymbol
\emailsymbol
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should use the `\emailsymbol` and `\phonesymbol` commands.